# How to move old Gitlab server to new one?

Tags: gitlab

I have local Gitlab server running on 
CentOS 6.4 with GitLab Version 7.8.1 - called A

I want to prepare new server with 
CentOS7 with latest Gitlab version 12.0.3 - called B

I need to move all the Gitlab users and data   from A to B.

I saw [instruction](https://www.tienle.com/2016/05-24/migrate-gitlab-to-new-server.html) that I need first to install on B the old Gitlab version of A and then upgrade the Gitlab on B to the newer version of gitlab.

The problem is that I cannot find the old Gitlab version 7.8.1 for [download](https://packages.gitlab.com/app/gitlab/gitlab-ce/search?q=&filter=all&filter=all&dist=).

How can I install server B to have the newest version of Gitlab with the data from server A?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not upgrade before migration?

Comment: In the instruction I follow (link above), they said that I must to have the same Gitlab version, then I can restore the backup from the old server and only then I can upgrade the Gitlab on the new server. Do you have other instruction I can follow?

Comment: Your description in the question suggests you know how to upgrade version of gitlab on your server B. What's your problem doing the same already on server A?

Comment: I dont want to upgrade server A.  I create new server B, with new OS. I want to prepare server B without interrupt the users using A. then just do the switch.